# Is there a more generalized form of the curves called the conic sections using the point definition.

Tags: geometry

I know that $5$ points uniquely define any conic sections in $2$ Dimensions. I also know that only $3$ are needed to define any circle in $2$ Dimensions and for a line only it's only $2$. lines are in the group of circles and circles are in the group of conic sections. Is there a "Bigger" group of curves in $2$ Dimensions then the conic section that take $6$ or more points to define and contains the conic sections.

This is my first question hope it's good.

Comment: Simple conics are in the form $ay^2 + bx^2 + cy + dx + e = 0$. Just adding any independent terms to that like say $ay^2 + bx^2 + cy + dx + e + fx^3 = 0$, will generalize the conics (conics are the special case $f=0$) and will require 6 points to define.

Comment: Or do you want a group of curves that have a name and has been studied? Unlikely to be one with only 6 points.

Comment: @SenZen sorry for answering 19 hours later I had school Yea That works as an answer thanks (: